# MySQL UNIX_TIMESTAMP with variables?

Tags: php, mysql

Is there any way to pass a condition into `UNIX_TIMESTAMP()`?

eg : `UNIX_TIMESTAMP(-24hr)` <- this doesn't work

This returns all records that are newer than the current unix timestamp :

```
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM events WHERE event_date > UNIX_TIMESTAMP() ORDER BY event_date ASC';
```

But I would like to return all records that are newer than the current unix timestamp - 24hrs to allow for timezone differences.

Can it be done with the `UNIX_TIMESTAMP()` function alone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try below

```
SELECT * FROM events 
 WHERE event_date > UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 24 Hour)) ORDER BY event_date ASC
```

OR use shorthand version as @Madhur Bhaiya suggested

```
 SELECT * FROM events 
     WHERE event_date > UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW()- INTERVAL 24 Hour) ORDER BY event_date ASC
```

Comment: That's the one. Thank you :)

Comment: I will as soon as I can

Comment: Just in case anybody else is after this solution there is an extra parenthesis needed : `UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 24 Hour))`

Comment: @spice you can avoid date_sub function and write the shorthand version : `unix_timestamp(now() - interval 24 hour)`

Comment: @Madhur Ahh thank you that's really what I was looking for.